# View page generates RuntimeBinderException, works anyway

Tags: razor, binding, servicestack

I am trying to use ServiceStack Razor in my project. I set up a very simple DTO:

```
namespace ModelsWeb.Diagnostics
{       
   [Route("/echo")]
   [Route("/echo/{Text}")]
   public class Echo
   {
      public string Text { get; set; }          
   }

   public class EchoResponse 
   {
      public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
      public string Result { get; set; }
   }
}
```

And a service to go with it:

```
namespace Rest.Services
{
   public class EchoService : Service
   {
      public object Any(Echo request)
      {
         return new EchoResponse {Result = request.Text};
      }
   }
}
```

Note that the DTO and the service are in different namespaces. This is because I'm building two applications at once -- the server and the thick client -- and I put all the DTOs in a separate class library that they both depend on. This way, the client can reference just that class library, and no other server-side code. I am using Razor to provide a Web interface to some of the server functionality.

Anyway, I also wrote a simple view for my Echo service:

```
@using ServiceStack.Razor
@using ModelsWeb.Diagnostics

@inherits ViewPage<EchoResponse>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Echo Response";
    Layout = "BasePage";
}

<h1>You typed: @Model.Result</h1>
```

When I type `"http://localhost:62061/echo/hello2"` into the browser, I get an error on my log:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceStack.Razor.Compilation.RazorDynamicObject' 
to 'ModelsWeb.Diagnostics.EchoResponse'
```

However, the template still works, and I see the expected result in the browser. What's going on here ? Am I doing anything wrong ? If not, how can I suppress this exception ?

Comment: Hm isn't that the same issue as here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/536

Comment: @Giedrius: it's possible, but then, my view is still being rendered correctly; if I access, f.ex., "/echo/hello", I see the string, "You typed: hello". I don't think this is the case with the linked issue.